# Перевести на с++ с паскаля.. решенную задачку

Tags: pascal, c++

Последовательность 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, …, состоящая из нулей и единиц строится так: первый ее элемент равен 1, а остальные получаются из предшествующих с помощью логической операции отрицания: not(1) = 0, not (0) = 1. Второй элемент равен отрицанию первого, третий и четвертый – отрицанию первого и второго соответственно и т.д. По заданному n вычислить n-ый член указанной последовательности.
примерный код на паскале

Код Pascal:  может сможете перевести на с++
думаю вместо trunc -> floor

```
Uses Crt;
Var i,k,N,indm:integer;
    m:array[1..300000]of boolean;
Begin
  m[1]:=true;
  indm:=trunc(power(2,k));
  N:=98568;
  repeat
    for i:=1 to indm do
      m[indm+i]:=not(m[i]);
    if indm>=N then
      break;
    inc(k);
    indm:=trunc(power(2,k));
  until false;
  write(N);
  if m[N]=false then
    write(0:2)
  else
    write(1:2);
End.
```

Comment: Перевести-то несложно, но лень. А что у вас конкретно не получается?

Кстати, `trunc` не нужен, степень двойки считайте как `1 << k`.

Ещё: что-то я не вижу инициализации `k` в вашей программе. Вы уверены, что она правильная?

Comment: проверил, нет, она неправильная

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваше решение ресурсоемко.
Я бы сделал так:

```
#include <iostream>

int GetMinGrade(int x)
{
    x--;
    while (!(x & (x - 1)))
        x--;

    return x;   
}

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    if (n == 1)
        std::cout << 1;
    else if (n == 2)
        std::cout << 0;
    else
    {
        int k = 0;
        while(n > 2)
        {
            n -= GetMinGrade(n);
            k++;
        }

        if (((n == 1) && (k % 2 != 0)) || ((n == 2) && (k % 2 == 0))) 
            std::cout << 1;
        else
            std::cout << 0;
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: int GetMinGrade(int x)
{
    x--;
    while (!(x & (x - 1)))
        x--;

    return x;   
} что она делает?

Comment: @Janycz что делает функция? 
 while (!(x & (x - 1)))

Comment: Уменьшает параметр на единицу. Если получается число 2^n, то уменьшает ещё. Т.е. результат не может быть 0, 1, 2, 4 и т.д.

Comment: @janycz

    int GetMinGrade(int x) {
      int a = x;
      while (x = x & (x - 1)) a = x;
      return a;   
    }

так?